# PHP replace everything between curly brackets?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I suck with preg I will never learn it :(  This shouldn't be hard can I please have a code example to replace everything between curly brackets, including spaces, everything?  Like:

```
$string = preg_replace('{.*?}#si', '', $string);
```

or something?

Answer (score 10):

You were missing the initial `#` delimiter:

```
'#\{.*?\}#s'
```

See it working online: [ideone](https://ideone.com/Vl9Qq)

A couple of other minor points:

- The `i` modifier is unnecessary here since you don't have any letters in the pattern.
- It's a good idea to escape `{` and `}` in regular expressions to avoid confusion with their use as quantifiers, though it's not strictly necessary in this case.

Comment: thanks for the reply but all it did was remove the first bracket and everything inbetween the brackets remained.

Comment: @John Jenkins: As a wild guess, I'd imagine you forgot the `\}` or else you have an extra space or other character just before the final `#`. Post the code you tried if you want more specific help.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code you gave me.  I am trying something different now, by trying to slowly modify a code for something else:    $string = preg_replace('#([{.*?}])*?([{.*?}])#e', "('\t$2')", $string);   It adds a tab after every period and question mark though, I would like for it to do that for everything between all brackets though.

Comment: @John Jenkins: Souds like your copy+paste key is broken then, because when I copy+pasted it it worked fine... See the update to my answer: I added a link to ideone that shows it working correctly. I suggest you post the exact code you tried otherwise I can only guess at what you did wrong...

Comment: $string = preg_replace('#\{.*?\}#s', "", $string);  works for you?  All it does for me is delete the first bracket.  Basically I am trying to indent everything inside of if () { $blah = 1; }  if, while, and foreach statements.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your other questions, it seems that you want to use this for beautifying your code.  While many editors have this functionality built into them for a single file, I imagine you want to apply this to a bunch of files.  If this is the case, see https://github.com/clbustos/PHP_Beautifier.

**Edit due to comments:** Then you won't want to use regex, honestly.  Use the [php tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php).

Comment: I am trying to make my own beautifier

Comment: @JohnJenkins: By requesting other people write it for you for money?

Comment: I am offering it totally free with no ads I will be using it myself mostly